# DateTime ToUniversalTime() changes Ticks value

Tags: .net, datetime

When I call `ToUniversalTime()` on a DateTime object, the method seems to return a new DateTime object representing a different time entirely.  I expected it to just martial across time zones.

The code

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(635229891600000000);

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
```

outputs

```
12/18/2013 6:46:00 PM
12/19/2013 12:46:00 AM
```

which is exactly what I expect.

However, if I look at the Ticks values of the DateTime objects

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(635229891600000000);

Console.WriteLine(dt.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks.ToString());
```

the output is

```
635229891600000000
635230107600000000
```

which means that the output of `ToUniversalTime` actually has a different Ticks value from the input.

The Ticks property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since the constant `DateTime.MinValue`.

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `ToUniversalTime` method returns "an object whose Kind property is Utc, and whose time is UTC equivalent to the value of the current DateTime object".  How can two DateTime objects be UTC equivalent if they have different Ticks values, and therefore represent different times?

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate explains it perfectly. `Ticks` ignores the timezone information so as midnight on the 19th **is** different to 6 pm on the 18th.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just posted a duplicate. :looks sheepish:

Comment: Don't be. I only found it when I was verifying the answer I was about to post :)

Comment: Yep.  Unlike JavaScript `Date` or `java.util.Date` and many others, .NET's `DateTime` basis the internal ticks relative to it's `.Kind` property, rather than always by UTC.  See also Jon Skeet's post: [What's Wrong with DateTime anyway?](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)